# Why does it take too long for my shortcut to run my process?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-shell, windows-explorer

I created a shortcut to my UI process on a user's desktop using [IShellLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774950(v=vs.85).aspx)/[IPersistFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687223(v=vs.85).aspx) (after a consent from a user.) The shortcut is nothing but a path with command line parameters:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Product\process.exe" -spo="T +v"

So I'm testing this shortcut in several virtual machines by double-clicking it (in Windows 7 OS) and in one machine (where OS was installed somewhat long ago) when I double-click my shortcut, it **takes about 15 seconds** for my process to start. (I can tell that by placing the logging method in the beginning of my process.) While in other (newer) copies of OS the shortcut starts my process almost immediately.

So I'm curious why is this happening?

Does Windows cache those shortcuts somewhere that may cause this delay?

Comment: Did you check that after clicking the shortcut it really takes 15sec before the process turns up in Task manager or similar?

Comment: And if you run the same command line from a dos prompt or the Win+R box do you see the same delay?

Comment: @stijn: Like I said, "I can tell that by placing the logging method in the beginning of my process"

Comment: @JonathanPotter: An interesting discovery. I put that OS into sleep mode and then when woken up the shortcut now works as expected.

Comment: *I can tell that by placing the logging method in the beginning of my process* that is exactly what I'm asking: even if your logging is the first line in main(), or happens in a static initializer, there still is a bunch of code in your process which runs earlier than that. Meaning that even if you see your logging starting at time x, you cannot know for sure that also means your process started at time x. It is likely, but not 100% guaranteed.

Comment: @stijn: The process quits as soon as it receives this command. It's a way to initiate a deeper service action. That is why just checking Task Manager won't be a good way to go here.

Comment: Good point. Maybe something [like this](http://www.eventtracker.com/newsletters/how-to-use-process-tracking-events-in-the-windows-security-log/) can help, or sysinternals procmon or so?